# User Mouse Click on Objects for Java

Tags: java, swing, object, events, jpanel

Having trouble with map that I am trying to make. What I am trying to do is make a grid map of a floor of a building on my campus. The floor as a whole is a square with different rooms attached to the hallway. I am in the process of making a map for people that are in a room. Right now, what I have "hard-coded" is the coordinates of the square (JPanel) that I wanted to use it to say someone is in there. I use the JPanel[][] grid to store the squares into rows and cols. What I would like to know is how to detect a mouse click on one of the JPanel objects rather than just the x and y coordinates of the frame.

Also, as I know, I know my code could definitely use improvement so if there's a better way to do this, please feel free to let me know.

Thank you.

```
import javax.swing.*;



import java.util.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;


public class Example extends JPanel {

    enum Token {VIDE, CERCLE_BLEU, CERCLE_ROUGE}

    private static final int ICON_W = 35;

    private JPanel[][] grid;




    Example(int rows, int cols) {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 1, 1));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);


        createGrid(rows, cols);

        Click click = new Click();
        this.addMouseListener(click);


    }



    void createGrid(int rows, int cols) {
        boolean personTrapped = false;
        grid = new JPanel[rows][cols];
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                grid[r][c] = new JPanel();
                grid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
                grid[r][c].setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                grid[r][c].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ICON_W, ICON_W));
                add(grid[r][c]);

            }
        }
        /*
         * Path for floor in building
         */
        grid[1][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[1][2].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[1][3].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[1][4].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[1][5].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[1][6].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[1][7].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[1][8].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        grid[2][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[3][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[4][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[5][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[6][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[7][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[8][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        grid[2][8].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[3][8].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[4][8].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[5][8].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[6][8].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[7][8].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[8][8].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        grid[8][1].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[8][2].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[8][3].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[8][4].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[8][5].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[8][6].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[8][7].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

        // Rooms in building
        grid[0][3].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[2][4].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[0][6].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[3][9].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[5][7].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[7][9].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[9][7].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[7][5].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[9][3].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[7][0].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[5][2].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        grid[3][0].setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);


    }




    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
        {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("RIC Emergency Map");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                Example example = new Example(15, 10);
                frame.add(example);

                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
                {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) 
                    {

                        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Do you want to Exit ?", "Exit Confirmation : ",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
                        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
                          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                        else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
                          frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                    }

                });

                frame.getGlassPane().setVisible(true);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.pack();
                //frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setResizable(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}



class Move implements MouseMotionListener
{

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}

class Click implements MouseListener
{
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(e.getPoint());
        if (e.getX() >= 150 && e.getX() <= 185 && e.getY() >= 73 && e.getY() <= 108)
        {
            System.out.println("There is somebody in this room!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Oh no, there isn't anyone in this room. Hurry! Keep looking!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}
```

Comment: Why not simply add a MouseLIstener to the JPanel cells in the grid?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply create a MouseListener (or better MouseAdapter), and add it to each JPanel cell in your JPanel grid when you create the grid.

For example if you had a MouseAdapter called MyMouse:

```
grid = new JPanel[rows][cols];
MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
        grid[r][c] = new JPanel();
        grid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
        Color color = data[r][c] == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.DARK_GRAY;
        grid[r][c].setBackground(color);
        grid[r][c].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ICON_W, ICON_W));
        grid[r][c].addMouseListener(myMouse); // ***** here, add the listener)
        add(grid[r][c]);

    }
}
```

would work:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Example2 extends JPanel {
    // enum Token {
    //     VIDE, CERCLE_BLEU, CERCLE_ROUGE
    // }
    private static final int ICON_W = 35;
    private JPanel[][] grid;

    public Example2(int[][] data) {
        int rows = data.length;
        int cols = data[0].length;

        setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols, 1, 1));
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red));
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        createGrid(data);
    }

    private void createGrid(int[][] data) {
        int rows = data.length;
        int cols = data[0].length;
        grid = new JPanel[rows][cols];
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        for (int r = 0; r < grid.length; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < grid[r].length; c++) {
                grid[r][c] = new JPanel();
                grid[r][c].setOpaque(true);
                Color color = data[r][c] == 0 ? Color.WHITE : Color.DARK_GRAY;
                grid[r][c].setBackground(color);
                grid[r][c].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ICON_W, ICON_W));
                grid[r][c].addMouseListener(myMouse);
                add(grid[r][c]);

            }
        }
    }

    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JPanel source = (JPanel) e.getSource();
            int r = -1;
            int c = -1;
            for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
                for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
                    if (grid[row][col] == source) {
                        r = row;
                        c = col;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            Color color = source.getBackground();

            System.out.printf("Cell: [%d, %d] color white: %b%n", c, r, color.equals(Color.WHITE));
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        int[][] data = {
                {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                {0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0},
                {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0},
                {1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1},
                {0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        };
        Example2 mainPanel = new Example2(data);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("RIC Emergency Map");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

In this example, I get the JPanel cell via the MouseEvent's `.getSource()` method. I then iterate through the grid to find the coordinates of the cell. I can also extract its background color and see if it's white or not.

```
private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JPanel source = (JPanel) e.getSource();

        // initially set row and column to -1
        int r = -1;
        int c = -1;

        // iterate through the grid finding out which cell is source
        for (int row = 0; row < grid.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < grid[row].length; col++) {
                if (grid[row][col] == source) {
                    r = row;
                    c = col;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        Color color = source.getBackground();

        System.out.printf("Cell: [%d, %d] color white: %b%n", c, r, color.equals(Color.WHITE));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it. Working with source.getBackground is even more help for my project!